# asynchronous request/response with jquery ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, asynchronous

I have a javascript file that call with $ajax a php script.

```
$.ajax({
    url : "myscript.php",
    success : function (data) {
          doSomething();
    },
    error : function (data) {
                  doSomethingElse();
    }
});
```

My php script will print more output during the process, one at a time.

Can I visualize these output asynchronously while the php script is processing?

Or I have to wait the end and show all togheter the output string from php script?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot retrieve parts of the response until the response is complete. You will have to implement AJAX requests that provide status information.

Comment: This will require some effort. You can find related questions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673562/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569394/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876945/.